# ¿Escribir arreglo en word desde laravel usando php word?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy utilizando la librería php word en mi proyecto con laravel, funciona correctamente,lo que hago es usar una plantilla word y agregarle valores usando TemplateProcessor, el problema que presento es al momento de querer escribir en la plantilla word un arreglo dinámico, que contiene los valores de una consulta a la bd.
el arreglo es: nombreacti1['futbol','natacion','beisbol'].

Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera, adjunto el codigo:

```
$sqlclientes="SELECT * FROM datos_clientes";


$datos_clientes = DB::select($sqlclientes);




foreach ($datos_clientes as $datos_cli) {
    $nombre_cli=$datos_cli->nombre_cli;
    $empresa_cli=$datos_cli->empresa_cli;
    $correo_cli=$datos_cli->correo_cli;
    $ciudad_cli=$datos_cli->ciudad_cli;
    $direccion_cli=$datos_cli->direccion_cli;
    $fecha_cli=$datos_cli->fecha_cli;
    $objetivo_ =$datos_cli->objetivo_;
    $referencia_= $datos_cli->referencia_;
}


//Aqui creamos el word con texto de prueba


// Abriendo la plantilla
$TemplateProcessor= new TemplateProcessor(Storage_path('Estudio_Conexion.docx'));
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('nombre_cliente',$nombre_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('nombre_empresa',$empresa_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('Correo',$correo_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('direccion',$direccion_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('fecha',$fecha_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('referencia',$referencia_);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('objetivo',$objetivo_);

$TemplateProcessor->setValue('actividades',$nombreacti1);


$TemplateProcessor->saveAs('cot1.docx');
return response()->download('cot1.docx');
```

En el word asigno la variable actividades de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que ese arreglo se insertara como una lista en esa parte del documento, pero al hacerlo de esta manera me tira error(Array to string conversion) y el documento descarga dañado.

Comment: si lo queres ver como palabras separadas por coma: `implode(", ",$nombreacti1);`

Comment: lo que quiero es que dejen un salto de linea, en ese caso como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usando la información que proporciono alo Malberez, realice la siguiente solucion, la adjunto aqui por si a alguien le sirve:

```
$sqlclientes="SELECT * FROM datos_clientes";


$datos_clientes = DB::select($sqlclientes);




foreach ($datos_clientes as $datos_cli) {
    $nombre_cli=$datos_cli->nombre_cli;
    $empresa_cli=$datos_cli->empresa_cli;
    $correo_cli=$datos_cli->correo_cli;
    $ciudad_cli=$datos_cli->ciudad_cli;
    $direccion_cli=$datos_cli->direccion_cli;
    $fecha_cli=$datos_cli->fecha_cli;
    $objetivo_ =$datos_cli->objetivo_;
    $referencia_= $datos_cli->referencia_;
}


//Aqui hago el implode con el salto de linea de word usando el arreglo 
$var=implode(" </w:t><w:br/><w:t> ",$nombreacti1);

// Creating the new document...
$TemplateProcessor= new TemplateProcessor(Storage_path('Estudio_Conexion.docx'));
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('nombre_cliente',$nombre_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('nombre_empresa',$empresa_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('Correo',$correo_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('direccion',$direccion_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('fecha',$fecha_cli);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('referencia',$referencia_);
$TemplateProcessor->setValue('objetivo',$objetivo_);

$TemplateProcessor->setValue('algo',$var);


$TemplateProcessor->saveAs('cot1.docx');
return response()->download('cot1.docx');
```